# C#: How to compare two dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to compare a date stored in a table in the form `DD/MM/YYYY` with the current date.

I need to know if it is earlier or later than `DateTime.Now` ...

Does someone have an idea to suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the date is stored in a database table as a string?

Comment: Are you reading the date from the table, then comparing in C#?  Or needing to pass DateTime.Now to a query to compare?

Comment: Do you mean table or data grid view/ list view

Comment: You could use time span aswell, see [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381401/how-do-you-compare-datetime-objects-using-a-specified-tolerance-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Compare` for this:

```
var result = DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text), DateTime.Today);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to parse your time stamps into DateTime objects and then compare as you like.

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact("12/03/2009", "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

See more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) method as such:

```
date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text)
date2 = DateTime.Today
var result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2)
string relationship

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
```